# Extract string from a long string in scala

Tags: regex, scala

I want to extract the useful fields from a string object like the following one

```
Request(Some(8454439),Some(16872692),Some(0.0.0.0),Some(8281008),Some(ArrayBuffer(845434399)),Some(129032),Some(3),Some(Profile),Some(en),None,None,None,None,Some(true),None,Some(Food),None,Some(Fish))
```

It has 18 fields in total, and what I want to do is assign them to 18 different strings and extract useful info if it is `Some(X)`, otherwise set the string to `None`.

For example in this case, the string array in the response should be

```
val results = Array("8454439", "16872692", "0.0.0.0", "8281008", "ArrayBuffer(845434399)",
"129032", "3", "Profile", "en", "None", "None", "None", "None", "true", "None",
"Food", "None", "Fish")
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Can you please clarify? Maybe provide some example pseudo code?

Comment: Hey Andy, I add an example response above.

Comment: How do you get the list of items from the `Request` object?

Comment: I think what they're asking for is an example of the string you want to parse - the answer you want is most likely a regex, and this is hard to write without knowing what you're trying to match against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get the list of items somehow, you could do something like this with a `Seq[Option[Any]]`:

```
val items: Seq[Option[Any]] = ???
items.map(_.getOrElse("None").toString)
```

But if you only have the output of `Request.toString`, this will get you most of the way there:

```
val s = "Request(Some(8454439),Some(16872692),Some(0.0.0.0),Some(8281008),Some(ArrayBuffer(845434399)),Some(129032),Some(3),Some(Profile),Some(en),None,None,None,None,Some(true),None,Some(Food),None,Some(Fish))"
val pat1 = """Some\([\w.()]+?\)|None""".r
val pat2 = """Some\((.*)\)""".r
pat1.findAllIn(s).map {
  case pat2(some) => some
  case x => x
}.toList
// res0: List[String] = List(8454439, 16872692, 0.0.0.0, 8281008, ArrayBuffer(845434399, 129032, 3, Profile, en, None, None, None, None, true, None, Food, None, Fish)
```

My regex-fu isn't strong enough to keep the trailing parenthesis on the `ArrayBuffer` value, but otherwise this seems to work.

Comment: No. I do not have list of items now. I need to pattern match from the string to get the list of item. My question is how to use scala pattern match.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something along the lines of

```
val items = request.map {
    case Some(value) => value
    case None => "None"
}
```

To actually convert Some(ArrayBuffer(845434399)) to "ArrayBuffer(845434399)" though, you may need a nested match statement:

```
val items = request.map {
    case Some(value) => value match {
                            case strng: String => strng
                            case other => ???
                        }
    case None => "None"
}
```

Off the top of my head, not sure what to call to do it, but maybe one of the functions of the Any type would be of help.

Comment: Your first case statement can be simplified to `item.getOrElse("None")`.